# Is a finite monoid with left cancellation property always a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, monoid

I need to answer and show if a Monoid with left cancellation property always a group.

I managed to show that it is correct when cancellation property holds for both left and right (that was part a of the question), but I have a feeling i proved it wrong because i didn't use the right side at all.
what I did is :

M is finite though if $x \in M$ there is some $i \in N$ such that

$x = x^i$

then

$x*e = x*x^{i-1}$

so

$x^{i-1} = e$

then $x^{i-2}$ is the inverse of x

so i proved that G is a Group without using the right cancelation property.

where am I wrong..

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your very first assumption is wrong. In a finite monoid you don't need $x=x^i$ for some $i$ ($i$ may not exist).

Comment: what do you mean i may not exists? how come? if it is finite , we can't have $ x, x^2 , x^3..... $ we have to have an i that $x^i  = e $ . no?

Comment: If you don't have cancellation, you can only say that $x^i = x^j$ for some $i \not= j$, but you cannot force $i$ to be $1$.

Comment: why? if $x^i = x^j$ and i < j , then $x^{j-i} = e$ then $x^{j-i+1} = x$ am I wrong?

Comment: Well, you are now using cancellation.

Comment: only left cancelation.. no?

Comment: ok got it . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every finite monoid $M$ with left (or right) cancellation is a group, because the mapping $x\mapsto ax$ is injective, and since $M$ is finite, it is already bijective by the pigeonhole (box) principle. Hence $M$ is a group. 
Your argument above is not correct as demonstrated in the comments, but it can be corrected by using the cancellation property.

Comment: The OP asks where is the mistake in his argument.

Comment: @Crostul You have explained this mistake already. Finally one needs some "box" argument and cancellation.